# EMR 5.0 + Spark getting stack at endless loop

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, emr, amazon-emr

i am trying to deploy **Spark 2.0 Streaming** over **Amazon EMR 5.0**.
it seems that the application is getting stuck at endless loop with the log
"endless loop of "INFO Client: Application report for application_14111979683_1111 (state: ACCEPTED)"
and then exit.

Here is how i am trying to submit it through the command line:

> aws emr add-steps --cluster-id  --steps
>   Type=Spark,Name="Spark
>   Program",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--class,,s3://.jar]

any idea ?

thanks,
Eran

---

```
16/08/30 15:43:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
16/08/30 15:43:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
16/08/30 15:43:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/08/30 15:43:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/08/30 15:43:27 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/08/30 15:43:27 INFO Client: Submitting application application_14111979683_1111 to ResourceManager
16/08/30 15:43:27 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_14111979683_1111
16/08/30 15:43:28 INFO Client: Application report for application_14111979683_1111 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/08/30 15:43:28 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1472571807467
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://xxxxxx:20888/proxy/application_14111979683_1111/
     user: hadoop
16/08/30 15:43:29 INFO Client: Application report for application_14111979683_1111 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

---

and this the exception thrown:

```
16/08/31 08:14:48 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1472630652740_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1472630652740_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 13
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://ip-10-0-0-8.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1472630652740_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1472630652740_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 13
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=13: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: is that set of args correct? `[--deploy-mode,cluster,--class,,s3://.jar]` s3://.jar is certainly not a real path to anything.

Comment: not it is not the full path. it seems that it was removed from some reason when i wrote the question.

Comment: here is the real exception which is thrown:

Comment: INFO Client: Application report for application_14111979683_1111 (state: ACCEPTED) means some partition of your calculation is done. It's good, if you think it's endless, it may because your dataset is very large so you have tons of partitions (you can check the container number in aws EMR dashboard), and EMR is not as stable as you expected, exit code 13 with that stack is like some connection problem, like, unhealthy connection. Not sure but that's all I can provide

Answer (score 0):

EMR is actually a wrapper to Yarn.
so, we need to add "--master yarn" as an argument to the deployment command line.
Example:
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXXXX --steps Type=Spark,Name="Spark Program",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--class,com.xxx.MyMainClass,s3://]

Another thing which is needed, is removing 'sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]")',
from the initialization of spark conf.